# ListView to open hyperlinks in android

Tags: java, android, listview

Is there any way in to Show Names like

 `"TechCrunch"
"Twit"
"NASA"`

in the listview and when the user clicks on one of them , it should open an intent with the link for corresponding Websites listed.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: I have done it and it wasn't very difficult, but it's been long enough that I would have to find the code to know what I did.  I ended up with an internal database and the ListView was simply displaying a subset of the data and applying the hyperlink from the database to each row.

Comment: Do you have the corresponding websites stored in a database?

Comment: @Ahmad, I am not using a database at the moment.

Comment: @Abiessu :Seems like a good idea. I will try this. But I still want to know if its possible to do that without database thing.

Comment: @JPro: like I said, I don't recall the details, but I would imagine that if the list that a ListView is capable of displaying can contain multiple items per list element, then the display element function of the ListView can be overridden to handle the data.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want the `ListView` to be generated by a database and you want to add every website to the adapter of your `ListView` yourself, then you can do the following.

You would have to create an `Item` class, that looks like this:

```
public class Item {

    private String mName;
    private int mLink;

    public Item(String name, int link) {

        this.mName = name;
        this.mLink = link;
    }

    public int getLink() {

        return mLink;
    }

    public void setLink(int link) {

        this.mLink = link;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {

        this.mName = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return this.mName;
    }
}
```

and then set the adapter of your ListView like this:

```
List<Item> dataForTheAdapter = new ArrayList<Item>();

// add some data
dataForTheAdapter.add(new Item("Apple", "www.Apple.com"));
dataForTheAdapter.add(new Item("Microsoft", "www.Microsoft.com"));
dataForTheAdapter.add(new Item("Google", "www.Google.com"));

mContext = MyActivity.this;
// R.layout.row is a layout, that contains only one TextView
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(mContext, R.layout.row, dataForTheAdapter);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Now set an `OnItemClickListener` to your `ListView`.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String url = mAdapter.getItem(position).getLink();
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need two string arrays:

1. names that users see on the list_view;
2. hyperlinks that we want to direct user to go.

In the array.xml:

```
<string-array name="search_provider_name_array">
    <item>Google</item>
    <item>Yahoo</item>
    <item>Bing</item>
    <item>Baidu</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="search_provider_link_array">
    <item>https://www.google.com</item>
    <item>https://www.yahoo.com</item>
    <item>https://www.bing.com</item>
    <item>https://www.baidu.com</item>
</string-array>
```

In the layout_search_provider.xml it contains a list view:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lv_search"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>
```

In your activity:

```
public class SearchProvider implements  AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    private ListView lv_search;
    private String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.search_provider_name_array);
    private String[] links = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.search_provider_link_array);

    //..

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(View v, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        lv_search= (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_search);

        ArrayAdapter sAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
        lv_search.setAdapter(sAdapter);
        lv_search.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        if(i<links.length){
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(links[i]); 
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

When your list is dynamic, you can the following method(s) to update your listview.

- move the code in onCreateView() into onResume().
- sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();